# Creating scatterplots using ggplot on a long format dataset to be subsequently used in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have been adhering to the tidy data principles and have converted my data frame into a long data type format. However, after doing so, I realized that it is difficult for me to create scatterplots from long data.

The following looks something like my data. There are three columns: subject id, key, and value. The column "key" refers to the particular question number that the subject has completed, with the "value" column referring to the actual value for that given question. For some questions, there might be blanks on "value" column as subjects failed to complete them.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
             key = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
                     "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2",
                     "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3"),
             value = c(1, NA, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3, NA, 1, 8, 2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 1, 5, NA, 1, 5, 8, NA, 3))
```

I have tried the following code to create a scatterplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x = value[key == "Q1"], y = value[key == "Q2"])) + geom_point()
```

However, R prompted me with the error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data" even though I have used na.omit to remove missing cases.

I have searched on Stackoverflow and have found two similar threads. The first thread (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314389/creating-scatter-plot-by-ggplot-for-long-format-data)) did not have an answer while a second "somewhat similar" thread (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618041/scatter-plot-in-ggplot-one-numeric-variable-across-two-groups)) recommended that the data is too tidied. For the latter, does this mean that I should "untidy" my data, making each question/variable occupying one column instead?

I intend to use such scatterplots in a Shiny application (if a long format data source works), using something like the following (which would not work):

```
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df(), aes(x = input$value[var1], y = input$value[var2])) + geom_point()
```

Thanks and much appreciated!

EDIT:

I have tried @patL solution from the comments. On its own, the code works. However, it did not work on Shiny.

The following is the code which I have used in Shiny:

```
# Define the User Interface for app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Scatter Plot App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x_scatter", "Select variable for x-axis", choices = unique(df$key)),
      selectInput("y_scatter", "Select variable for y-axis", choices = unique(df$key))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatter")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for app
server <- function(input, output) {
  scatter_data <- reactive({
    df %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      spread(key, value)
  })

  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(scatter_data(), aes(x = input$x_scatter, y = input$y_scatter)) + geom_point()
  })
}
```

When I run the app, the result is a scatter plot with one dot in the middle, which is incorrect. There are many more numeric variables (e.g. Q3, Q4, Q5, etc), but in this example, I have left them out.

Comment: As suggested in the second thread, I would go with a wider format and put each question as a variable.

Comment: @kluu As I intend to use multiple data sources, inputs, and outputs (e.g. plots) for my shiny app, won't using the same data source twice (one in long format for other plots, another in wide format for scatter plot) affect the performance of my shiny app?

Comment: Maybe this could work: `df %>%  na.omit() %>%  spread(key, value) %>%  ggplot(aes(x = Q1, y = Q2)) +   geom_point()`

Comment: @patL On its own, your code works. However, when I edit it and use it in Shiny, the scatter plots do not turn out correctly.

Comment: What is wrong with your plot?  It'll be easier to help you out

Comment: @patL Thanks for your patience. I have edited my question above to include an anonymized sample of my dataset and the Shiny code which I have tried using to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to answer my own question with @patL help. The scatterplot failed to work in Shiny as I used a `aes` in `ggplot`. When I used `aes_string` the scatterplot was displayed correctly.

@patL recommended the following dplyr pipe:

```
df %>% na.omit() %>% spread(key, value)
```

I have changed it to the following:

```
df %>% spread(key, value) %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

The above dplyr pipe would convert the data frame from a long to wide format first before removing rows with NA values. If I had used `na.omit` before `spread`, R will prompt a warning message that they have removed rows containing missing values every time I select a different column as an input for my scatterplot.

The actual working script for the Shiny App is as follow:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
             key = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
                     "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2",
                     "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3"),
             value = c(1, NA, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3, NA, 1, 8, 2, 1, 4, 6, 7, 1, 5, NA, 1, 5, 8, NA, 3))


ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Scatter Plot App"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("x_scatter", "Select variable for x-axis", choices = unique(df$key)),
          selectInput("y_scatter", "Select variable for y-axis", choices = unique(df$key))
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("scatter")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    scatter_data <- reactive({
         df %>%
             spread(key, value) %>%
             filter(complete.cases(.))
     })

    output$scatter <- renderPlot({
         ggplot(scatter_data(), aes_string(x = input$x_scatter, y = input$y_scatter)) + geom_point()
     })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @patL Thanks for your help. Managed to find a solution to my question!